# Isomorphism of finite dimensional topological vector space with $(\mathbf{R}^k,\mathcal{R})$

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $(T,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological vector space over $\mathbf{R}$ with finite positive dimension.

Is it true that there exists an isomorphism between $(T,\mathcal{T})$ and $(\mathbf{R}^k,\mathcal{R})$, for some integer $k>0$ and topology $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: How about taking the usual isomorphism and transposting the topology along it?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the topology is given on $T$ so your suggestion does not work.

Comment: @KCd Why not? The topology from $T$ gives one on the image.

Comment: The answer is no for a silly reason: the topology on $T$ could be the discrete topology. But if you impose some other conditions the answer is yes. The only nondiscrete Hausdorff topology making a finite-dimensional real vector space into a topological vector space is the usual one. The proof is subtle even in the one-dimensional case.

Comment: @KCd and what is wrong with the discrete topology?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft okay I see what you mean. Yes, you are right.

Comment: I wanted to interpret the question in a nontrivial way.

Comment: KCd, I did know about the result, adding the Hausdorff property :) Now sorry for the probably idiot question, but what happens if the topology coincides with the power set of T?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, the only topology of any importance on Euclidean space *as a vector space* is its usual topology. Sometimes to give weird counterexamples the discrete topology is used.